# Deploying application

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-ce

I'm just deploying a winform app that uses SqlCe. I'm using the 'Setup and Deployment\Setup Project' to customise my deployment. I've created a 'User's Application Data Folder' for all my sdf files to go into (from what I've read this is best practice, correct me if I'm wrong). Now I want to re-map (for lack of a better work) the connection strings from

```
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\My.sdf"
```

to

```
connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\My Application\My.sdf"
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I do this so as it work on multiple users and OS's (I believe putting the sdf files into C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\My Application is best for multi OS's)?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `AppData`-folder using the following:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Adding your desired path can be done using `Path.Combine`:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Roaming\\My Application");
```

The result-path is the AppData-folder for the user that runs the code.

Comment: Where do you put this code? I tried it but it didn't work. Do you need to modify the app.config datasource?

Comment: You'd have to change the connectionString when installing the program. This code retrieves that value; it is up to you to put it in the right place.